# How to loop through a class member vector's elements in the best way in C++?

Tags: c++, class, vector, element

I have a `class` A with a member `vector<class B>`. I would like to loop through this `vector` from outside `class` A in a clean way. I need to do operations on B using its public functions.

To do so, I thought of having a function `int get_next_element(B * in_B)`, where I can return 0 if I have correctly loaded the next element and -1 otherwise.

I thought of doing this by using an `iterator`, but I found two issues with this. First of all, I wasn't able to find a neat way to convert an `iterator` to a `pointer` (it seems I could use an `iterator` just like a `pointer`, but I'm unsure that's a good solution). Secondly, I would need to check if there's a value referenced by my `iterator`, and since the closest thing to a "null iterator" is the `.end()` element I can't figure out how I would then initialise it. If I initialise it (empty) and have the reference `.end()`, it wont refer to anything comparable if I add something to it.

I could have an extra `int` that keeps track of which element I'm at, but then I'd have to manage that `int` whenever I add elements, etc.

I considered placing the iteration code outside of `class` A, but I may need to change or access individual elements during the loop, so that would make a complex/big iteration block.

How would I solve this problem in a clean way (such as `int get_next_element(B * in_b)`)?

EDIT:
Here's some code:
Header:

```
class B {
  public:
    B();
    void set_size(int in_size);
    int get_size();
  protected:
    int mSize;
};

class A {
  public:
    A();
    void add_B(B in_B);
    int get_next_element(B * in_B);
  protected:
    std::vector<B> mObjects;
};
```

cpp file:

```
B::B() {
  // Stuff
}
void B::set_size(int in_size) {
  mSize = in_size;
}
int B::get_size() {
  return mSize;
}

A::A() {
  // Stuff
}
void A::add_B(B in_B) {
  mObjects.push_back(in_B);
}
int A::get_next_element(B * in_B) {
  // ToDo : handle elements
}
```

And main:

```
int main() {
  A test_a;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    B tmp_b;
    tmp_b.set_size(i);
    test_a.add_B(tmp_b);
  }
  B iterator_b;
  while (0 == get_next_element(& iterator_b)) {
    if (iterator_b.get_size > 2) {
      B tmp_b;
      tmp_b.set_size(iterator_b.get_size - 2);
      test_a.add_B(tmp_b);
      iterator_b.set_size(2);
    }
  }
}
```

So, basically `A` holds a bunch of `B`s and can help the main iterate through them and (in this example) cut them into smaller pieces while not having too much code in the `main`. There's quite a few dimensions/ways this will be done, which is partially why I'd like to "hide" as much of the code in `A`.

(This is a bit simplified, like the Bs may have to have internal relations, but basically that's the idea)

Comment: Can't `A` simply have a member function `const std::vector<B> & get_elements() const;`? (Preferably with an appropriate type alias for `std::vector<B>`.)

Comment: do you really need a `get_next_element` method? Why isn't a `begin()` / `end()` pair good for your use case?

Comment: @cdhowie Maybe it could, but it would mean I need to take care of the logic outside of `class A`. I need to change or add `B`'s depending on earlier `B`'s, so it seems cleaner to keep the logic for how to handle that within `A`.

@bolov I probably could that as well, but similarly then I would need to have that logic outside of `A`. Is it standard operating on the `iterator` like a `pointer`? (I know it's possible, but is it encouraged?)

Comment: You don't have to _handle_ it outside of `A` if you add `end` and `begin` members to `A`. Maybe `insert` and `find` members. You can keep your vector private if you would like, keeps your `A` class in control.

Comment: @lakeweb Sure, but it becomes more complicated if I need to add to the `vector`, does it not? I was trying a few options, and it seems both `.begin()` and `.end()` become unusable when I do so, so I'd have to handle resetting my iteration when I add at one of the stages. That's what I'd like to avoid handling outside `A`

Comment: @GreatName At this point you should give us some sample code that describes what you're trying to do, because right now the question is rather ambiguous. One possible solution, for example, would be a template member function that accepts a functor to call over each value in the vector, but we can't even tell if that would be a good approach because the question is vague. You say in your question _"I would like to loop through this vector from outside class A in a clean way"_ but then you tell us that you _don't_ want to loop from outside the class... so which is it!?

Comment: I think no one will give you accurate help without seeing what it is really about. Provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (along with what is being done with B objects, etc...)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I added some code. I need to get better at doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what I mean...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class B {
public:
    B(int in) :mSize(in) {}
    size_t mSize;
    void set_size(int in_size) {    mSize = in_size;}
    int get_size() {return mSize;}
};

class A {
    using container = std::vector<B>;
    using iterator = container::iterator;
    container mObjects;
public:
    void add_B(B in_B) { mObjects.push_back(in_B); }
    iterator begin() { return mObjects.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return mObjects.end(); }
};


int main() {
    A test_a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        test_a.add_B(B(i));
    }
    for( auto& item : test_a)
        if (item.get_size() > 2) {
            B tmp_b(item.get_size() - 2);
            item.set_size(2);
            test_a.add_B(tmp_b);
            break;//if using a vector, must break as vector can change/reallocate on 'add_B()'
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks pretty neat. I haven't tried the for-range loop with vectors; does it handle insertion "dynamically" (so it wont miss the newly added elements)? Are there any other drawbacks (for this context)?

Comment: You have all the benefits and restrictions of the underlying container. Like with a vector, iterators and references to the items should be considered invalid after an insertion. If this is an issue, use the likes of a `std::list`, and easy to change if you use the form above.

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip! One annoying thing I realised was that even though a `list` makes it possible to insert while looping, if I define `.begin()` when it's empty and then add something, it will interpret it as `.end()` (since they're the same when the container is empty) and thus follow with the end (so testing `== .begin()` wont be true afterwards).

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a [range-base for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (`C++1x`).

```
class A {
  private:
    std::vector<class B> vec;
  public:
    std::vector<class B>& get_vec() { return vec; }
};

A a_instance;
for (B &b : a_instance.get_vec()) {
    b.print();
    std::cout <<  "b = " <<  b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&b = " << &b << std::endl;
}
```

This, unfortunately, does not allow looking ahead, unless you keep track of index yourself.